# sqlalchemy - DetachedInstanceError when using a session as a contextmanager with sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm sure there is a duplicate somewhere but just couldn't find it. If you do, please mark this question as duplicate.

Consider a very basic model with no relations at all:

```
class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'matches'

    match_date = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    stadium = Column(String)
    opponent = Column(String)
    is_date_final = Column(Boolean)
```

And the DAL class:

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self, log_level):
        self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db/db.sqlite')
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
```

I'm baffled as to why this code works:

```
def get_next_matches(self):
    session = self.Session()
    next_matches = session.query(Match).all()
    session.close()

    return next_matches
```

However, the following code raises `DetachedInstanceError` as soon as the return value from `get_next_matches` is accessed.

```
...

@contextmanager
def create_session_scope(session_maker):
    """Provides a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = session_maker()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
...

def get_next_matches(self):
    with create_session_scope(self.Session) as session:
        next_matches = session.query(Match).all()

    return next_matches
```

Comment: It's the commit: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#committing.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Indeed. The solution, as explained in the link you provided is to call `session_maker` with `expire_on_commit=False`. Can you please make it into an answer?